# file upload in ajax by using php

Tags: php, file, upload, gmail

I wud like to use file upload(ajax/javascript with php) in my form that has other controls also.
when i uploaded an img it displays on the same form with delete option.
if i click on submit it goes into folder as well as database &
if i click on delete it deletes an img....
anybody can help me?pls
u knw gmail file upload exact like that

Answer (score 0):

It boils down to "Don't use XHR. Do use Flash or iframes". There are [libraries that will do the heavy lifting for you](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/uploader/).

Comment: the xhr doesnot support file upload.

Comment: @Adeel — It might be possible to persuade it to send file data, but I haven't bothered looking because you can't get the file data from the user's hard disk with JavaScript… which is why my answer said not to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Just use jQuery ajax upload plugin http://valums.com/ajax-upload/. It is actually not ajax, it's invisible iframe, but result is almost same.

For server-side you can use php with gd-library and some simple MySQL queries.

Comment: It is actually Ajax. Ajax does not mean XHR.